# Delete message generated by reminder in slack

Tags: slack

I deleted my reminders successfully in the /remind list. The issue is that the message generated is still showing in the channel. How can I delete the message ?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only delete the generated reminder messages if your reminder was set up for yourself in a direct message with `slackbot` -- e.g. `/remind me about stuff at 2:30PM`.

You can't delete messages generated from reminders if you set your reminder up for a private or public channel -- e.g. `/remind #channel about stuff at 2:30PM`.

Comment: Is there any way around this using the Slack API or some other trick? Can this message perhaps be deleted by Slack admins?

Comment: wondering if u found a solution for this.? I have a channel spammed with old reminders which I want to cleanup